# How to auto assign a user to a specific row of data in the database table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing a hospital management system.All i want is to assign a specific patient to a certain doctor once he/she has made the payment.I am using MySQL database and therefore i want the system to automatically assign that patient to the doctor without the need to select the doctor from the drop down.But before assigning the patient the system should check the doctor with fewer patients in pending in his/her account...

Any idea on how i can achieve this is much appreciated...

Regards

Comment: Have you tried anything already? We don't know your database structure and it's impossible to answer without it.

Comment: Yes i tried to use normal php to check which doctor has fewer patients and then assign the patient.Seems to work as i am having just three doctors to compare,but with an increase in the number of doctors i have to then go back to the codes and modify.I want it to be dynamic no matter the number of doctors.My database structure is that i have table called patients and another doctors,and it one to many thus one doctor can attend on or more patients.Is that helpful

Comment: Show me what you've already done to compare the 3 doctors.

Comment: if((count($first_doctor)<count($second_doctor)) && (count($first_doctor) < count($third_doctor)){
  $new_patient=new DoctorPatient();
  $new_patient->doctor_id = '1';
  $new_patient->save();
 }
 if((count($second_doctor)<count($first_doctor)) && (count($second_doctor)<count($third_doctor)){
  $new_patient=new DoctorPatient();
  $new_patient->doctor_id = '2';
  $new_patient->save();
 }
 if((count($third_doctor) < count($first_doctor)) && (count($third_doctor) < count($second_doctor)){
  $new_patient=new DoctorPatient();
  $new_patient->doctor_id = '2';
  $new_patient->save();
 }

Comment: I am using laravel framework

Comment: Can you post your database schema? My first thought is to just order your doctors by assigned patients in ascending order and then take the first result. This would give you the doctor with the least patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `Patient` and `Doctor` models.

The Migrations would be:

```
Schema::create('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('doctor_id');

    // Your patient columns here

    $table->timestamps();
});


Schema::create('doctors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    // Your doctor columns here

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then you can find the `doctor_id` that belongs to the least amount of patients:

```
$result = Patient::select('doctor_id')->selectSub('COUNT(*)', 'patient_count')->groupBy('doctor_id')->orderBy('patient_count')->first();
```

Then update the patient with that doctor id:

```
Patient::where('id', $patientId)->update(['doctor_id' => $result->doctor_id]);
```